# passing table name in stored procedure

Tags: mysql

I am trying to figure out how I can pass part of a table name into a stored procedure and get it to work.

query is

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS vorpaldev.searchLogId2$$
CREATE DEFINER = 'root'@'%'
PROCEDURE vorpaldev.searchLogId2 (userId varchar(300))
BEGIN
SET userId = CONCAT("log", userId);
SET @statment = "Select * from @userId ";
PREPARE stmt FROM @statment;
SET @a = userId;
EXECUTE stmt USING @a;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END
$$

DELIMITER
```

;

I am using

```
CALL searchLogId2 (131)
```

to call the code

I want the end results to execute as

```
Select * from log131
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well! are you going to create seperate table for each user????????? If yes, that is really bad.

I don't know but may be this is your answer. Why dont you pass complete userId in parameter argument 'log131' as

```
BEGIN
   SET @statment = concat('Select * from ',userId);
   PREPARE stmt FROM @statment;
   EXECUTE stmt USING userId;
   DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END
```

this will remove overhead of concat

Comment: actually what is really need its this:

Comment: What I am actually trying to figure out is this
I have several table that I need to join and one of those tables depends on what the logID is of another table
SO I need to pass that log is (which is an in) and put the work log in front of it - this will give me the name of the table I need to hit

SELECT * FROM logs l
    INNER JOIN items i ON l.logId = i.logId
    INNER JOIN activities a ON l.logId = a.logId
    INNER JOIN log100 l1 ON a.activityId = l1.activityId

With the table log100 dependant upon the LOG ID passing 
So I need to concat("log",@logID) to get log100 or log?

Comment: sorry about that ran out time to edit before - I did not design this database or I would have used a logEvents table instead of a NEW table for each log ID and its activities!